# Stop scroll while in scroll event IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, scroll

I'm having some issues with IE and this bit of code I put together.

What I want to happen is the following:

- A user can scroll freely while above the first footer, but not below it
- To reach below the footer only a click can allow it

I've managed to put together my intended behavior, however it isn't working properly on IE since it allows to scroll below the first footer and only then sets the `scrollTop` value. This [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/gikaz/9/edit) is working as intended on Chrome/Firefox/Safari.

What am I missing here to get this code working on IE?

**jQuery:**

```
var isAtBottom = false,
    isFarDown = false,
    wasClicked = false,
    scrollComplete = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollH = $(window).scrollTop(),
        windowH = $(window).height(),
        documentH = $(document).height(),
        footer = $('.footer'),
        breaker = $('.break');

  if (scrollH > (documentH - windowH - footer.height())){
    if(!wasClicked){
      //here is where IE goes south
      $('html, body').scrollTop(documentH - windowH - footer.height() - 1);
    }
  } else {
    if(wasClicked && scrollComplete){
        wasClicked=false;
        scrollComplete=false;
    }
  }
});

$('.scrollToEnd').click(function(){
    //sends you to top
    if (isAtBottom) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0},
            1200, function(){
                wasClicked = false;
            });
        return;
    }
    //is anywhere above the absolute bottom
    if (!isFarDown) {
        wasClicked = true;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height()},
            1200, function(){
                scrollComplete = true;
            });
    }
});
```

I've read through several answers on the subject and haven't found a way to stop the scroll event.

I've seen the `overflow` solution, yet it doesn't apply to the full scenario, although it does stop the scroll it removes the scrollbar and gives the whole website a wierd right to left movement. (I don't want to add `overflow:scroll` to keep the scroll there since not all pages will have overflow)

I have considered unbinding the scroll event either from the `'html, body'` elements and `window` to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Strange: Response time in IE10 is atleast 1/3rd of the response time in Chrome 35.0.1870.2 dev-m. Check this 1 out: http://jsbin.com/yixopisi/2/edit

Comment: @Daredev I changed you jsbin a bit for readability and i'm getting faster results on Chrome (between 0-1ms) against IE's (0-4ms)... Looking at those values, i'm assuming it's not the speed of the process itself, but something else. Still haven't got a clue as to what it might be :S http://jsbin.com/yixopisi/5/edit